# JavaFX8 How to set a label's ellipsis from the left-side not from the right-side?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

JavaFX 8 can auto ellipsisize Label's text started at the right side. For example, if there is a sentence 'Answer your own question', it may be ellipsisized to 'Answer your own que...' because there is no enough space to show the sentence completely.

But now, I want to ellipsize the left-side text, not the right-side. For example, if there is a sentence 'Answer your own question', I want to make it ellipsized to '...our own question'.

On Android, it can be easily implemented by setting the TextView's ellipsize attribute in a XML file, but on JavaFX, I have no idea to do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
label.setTextOverrun(OverrunStyle.LEADING_ELLIPSIS);
```

or

```
label.setTextOverrun(OverrunStyle.LEADING_WORD_ELLIPSIS);
```

depending on the exact behavior you want. ([Documentation is here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#textOverrunProperty))

You can also do this in FXML:

```
<Label text="Answer your own question" textOverrun="LEADING_ELLIPSIS"/>
```

or even in css:

```
.label {
    -fx-text-overrun: leading-ellipsis ;
}
```

(The latter will set the text overrun for all labels; you can use an id as the selector if you want to apply it to just one label.)